# Java - trying to deserialize a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, spring, deserialization

I am using Spring Boot (2.4.0-SNAPSHOT) and Java 14.

I have a byte array stored in a Postgres database (bytea). I am trying to convert it to a Java object.

I can execute the following successfully and the `businessRequest` is populated.

```
byte[] businessRequest = rs.getBytes("businessrequest");
```

Now when I try convert the `byte[]` to an `Object` using Springs `SerializationUtils`:

```
Object deserializedByteArray = SerializationUtils.deserialize(businessRequest);
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.jini.io.MarshalledInstance

**Question**

How do I convert the `byte[]` to a java object?

Comment: You already have a way to deserialize there. The right question for now must be *what is a `ClassNotFoundException` and how `net.jini.io.MarshalledInstance` is involved?*. There may be alternative ways to go about this, but chances are that question will remain.

Comment: That's a good question. Do you think the problem is with the data in the database?

Comment: No, I don't think that. I think the byte array you're deserializing is of an object whose class is (or directly or indirectly references) `net.jini.io.MarshalledInstance`, and Java cannot locate that class where the deserialization is being attempted.

Comment: It looks like the object saved to the database is a `net.jini.io.MarshalledInstance`.

Comment: Do you know how I would fix that?  Do I need to make sure that `MarshalledInstance` is in the classpath?

Comment: Of course. The class must be present when the object is being deserialized.

Comment: `net.jini.io.MarshalledInstance` is a class in [Apache River](https://river.apache.org/index.html)

Comment: @saka1029, thank you.  I add all the dependencies to my pom that are listed here, but it still does not have the `MarshalledInstance` https://river.apache.org/user-doc/maven-artifacts.html.  Strange thing is that the dependencies are not in the external libs.